# Passing data during PDF attachment generation

Tags: php, arrays, pdf, laravel-5

I am getting data from a Model, then passing it to generate a PDF attachment to be emailed.

However, I have a challenge getting the data on the PDF view side as I am required to pass as an array. See below;

```
$allTransaction = TblAirtimePurchaseInfo::where('org_name', '=', $user->org_name)->get();

$allTransaction = (array) $allTransaction;

$emails = $user->email;
$name = ['first_name' => $user->first_name];

Mail::send('emails.send_transactions_email', $name, function ($m) use ($emails, $allTransaction) {
$pdf = PDF::loadView('PDF.sendAllTransaction',['allTransaction' => $allTransaction])->stream();
$m->attachData($pdf, 'Transactions_for_' . date("Y-m-d") . '.pdf');
$m->to($emails)->subject('Transaction ' . date("Y-m-d") );        
 });
```

On the **PDF.sendAllTransaction view**

I am trying to get the values through a loop;

```
<table class="table no-margin" id="data">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th> ID </th>
        <th> Date </th>
        <th> Amount </th>
        <th> Phone Number </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

    @php 
      $allTransaction = (object) $allTransaction;
      $id = 1; 
    @endphp

    @foreach($allTransaction as $detail)
        <tr>
            <td> {{$id ++}} </td>
            <td> {{$detail->created_at}}</td>
            <td> {{$detail->amount}}</td>
            <td> {{$detail->phoneNumber}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However, I get **Trying to get property of non-object** error. How can I get the values on the view?

Anyone?

Comment: The problem is you are trying to convert object to array from this line of your code.
$allTransaction = (array) $allTransaction;
and in view file you are fetching data from object.

Comment: @pdshah3690 I however can not pass data as an object. It requires that you pass as an array. On the view I try to convert the array to object then access the data.

Comment: Instead of this '$allTransaction = (array) $allTransaction;'  
try to use this one $allTransaction = $allTransaction->toArray();

Comment: @pdshah3690 isn't the same? The question is how to get the values on the view?

Comment: In my case its working with this code
$filename = 'reports_'.date('Y_m_d').'.pdf';
        $pdf = PDF::loadView($view, compact('data'))->setPaper('a2', 'landscape');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Borrowing on @pdshah3690 comment;

This is what I did on my controller and passed as object.

```
$allTransaction = TblAirtimePurchaseInfo::where('org_name', '=', $user->org_name)->get();

$emails = $user->email;
$name = ['first_name' => $user->first_name];

Mail::send('emails.send_transactions_email', $name, function ($m) use ($emails, $allTransaction) {
$pdf = PDF::loadView('PDF.sendAllTransaction', compact('allTransaction'))->stream();
$m->attachData($pdf, 'Transactions_for_' . date("Y-m-d") . '.pdf');
$m->to($emails)->subject('Transaction ' . date("Y-m-d") );        
 });
```

The view remains unchanged. And I was able to pass `allTransaction` as an object to my view.